# Using JQuery on Ext Js elements

Tags: jquery, extjs

I am trying to capture a .keypress event from JQuery in some Sencha elements, but it seems that somehow Sencha is hiding them to JQuery.

I'll show a piece of code, that is simplier, but has the same problem:

```
        Ext.onReady(function(){

            $("#jquery").click(function() {
                alert('Handler for click called.');
            });

            var contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
                renderTo: document.body,
                width: 150,
                floating: false,
                plain: true,
                items: [{
                    text: 'button1',
                    id: 'jquery'
                },{
                    text: 'button2'
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"> I am a div </div>
</body>
```

My objective here is that when I click on button1 the alert's pop up is shown, but it doesn't happen. However, if I change the JQuery code to:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
alert('Handler for click called.');
});
```

And I click over the div content the pop up it is shown, so the library is correctly loaded.

I think it must be something related to how Sencha creates the html, which I have inspect, and I can see that button1 is like follows:

```
<a id="jquery" class="x-menu-item" hidefocus="true" unselectable="on" href="#"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-menu-item-icon " id="ext-gen7"><span class="x-menu-item-text" id="ext-gen8">button1</span></a>
```

But still I cannot use JQuery where I want.
Any idea or solution to access sencha elements with JQuery selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i dont know why do you wanna use ExtJS with jquery
 try avoiding using both because that will only increase the page times and wont add any new functionality
Extjs in itself is a pretty big library and surely supports DOM manipulation
Problem with your code is that Ext.onReady() event fires when all the dependencies have been loaded. ExtJS makes the HTML elements dynamically so at the time when this event is raised all the scrips are present but nothing has been created so there is no element with the id jquery hence you cannot access it via jquery
what i would suggest insted of this is to 
*put this peice of jquery code inside some afterrender event so that you are sure that the HTML element is present
*if you cant do this then use jquery `live` OR jquery `on` because they are function that can be used to assign event handlers to dynamically created elements.
*most prefrred would be to put a [listener in the ExtJS style](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View-cfg-listeners) to the element and Extjs will handle the raising of the event for you. Something like this

```
listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
            fn: function(){ console.log('click el'); }
        },
        dblclick: {
            element: 'body', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
            fn: function(){ console.log('dblclick body'); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes lot of sense, so it must be my problem, I'll try something to control that my function it's called after render the web, if I find any solution I'll post it.
The listeners' solution is okey also but my application is more complex, it was just and example, I have already used listeners in that way and is no what I need but thank you anyway!

Comment: thankx.. i would still ask you to use listeners with the buttons and avoid using jquery altogether

Comment: I will follow your advise, I won't use jQuery with the buttons, but I will need it for other purposes, so this example help me a lot.
Thank you very much!